# Find which HT-cores are sharing a physical core from /proc/cpuinfo

Tags: linux, cpu

There is a computer with two "Xeon(R) CPU           X5550  @ 2.67GHz" CPU. The Hyper-threading is enabled, so it looks like 16-core system, but really there is only 8 physical cores.

I know that when hyperthreading is enabled, each physical core is splitted into two virtual cores. I want to know, which pair of virtual cores shares a physical core and which are not. Or, how (in what order) will Linux enumerate HT-cores comparing to real cores. (enumerating is done for `sched_setaffinity` and `taskset` masks).

I have a dump of `/proc/cpuinfo` file from the system.

I think there are possible:

- CPU0-CPU7 are not sharing phys. core. CPU8-CPU15 too. But sharing is in pairs CPU0+CPU8, CPU(i)+CPU(i+8) and so on.
- or CPU0+CPU1 are from single physical, CPU2+CPU3, CPU(2*i)+CPU(2*i+1).
- or exotic  CPU0+CPU15 sharing, CPU1+CPU14 ...
- or random?

The hard moment in this case is that there are 2 physical dies of CPU (two sockets), and usual recommendation of using "physical id:" field can't help

The cpuinfo:

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 26
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5550  @ 2.67GHz
stepping    : 5
cpu MHz     : 2660.076
cache size  : 8192 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 8
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 16
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc ida nonstop_tsc pni monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm
bogomips    : 5320.15
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: [8]

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 26
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5550  @ 2.67GHz
stepping    : 5
cpu MHz     : 2660.076
cache size  : 8192 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 8
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc ida nonstop_tsc pni monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm
bogomips    : 5319.96
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: [8]

processor   : 2
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 26
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5550  @ 2.67GHz
stepping    : 5
cpu MHz     : 2660.076
cache size  : 8192 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 8
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 18
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc ida nonstop_tsc pni monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm
bogomips    : 5320.04
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: [8]

processor   : 3
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 26
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5550  @ 2.67GHz
stepping    : 5
cpu MHz     : 2660.076
cache size  : 8192 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 8
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 2
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc ida nonstop_tsc pni monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm
bogomips    : 5320.05
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: [8]

processor   : 4
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 26
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5550  @ 2.67GHz
stepping    : 5
cpu MHz     : 2660.076
cache size  : 8192 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 8
core id     : 2
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 20
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc ida nonstop_tsc pni monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm
bogomips    : 5320.04
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: [8]

processor   : 5
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 26
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5550  @ 2.67GHz
stepping    : 5
cpu MHz     : 2660.076
cache size  : 8192 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 8
core id     : 2
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 4
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc ida nonstop_tsc pni monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm
bogomips    : 5320.05
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: [8]

processor   : 6
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 26
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5550  @ 2.67GHz
stepping    : 5
cpu MHz     : 2660.076
cache size  : 8192 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 8
core id     : 3
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 22
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc ida nonstop_tsc pni monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm
bogomips    : 5320.03
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: [8]

processor   : 7
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 26
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5550  @ 2.67GHz
stepping    : 5
cpu MHz     : 2660.076
cache size  : 8192 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 8
core id     : 3
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 6
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc ida nonstop_tsc pni monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm
bogomips    : 5320.07
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: [8]

processor   : 8
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 26
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5550  @ 2.67GHz
stepping    : 5
cpu MHz     : 2660.076
cache size  : 8192 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 8
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 17
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc ida nonstop_tsc pni monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm
bogomips    : 5320.01
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: [8]

processor   : 9
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 26
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5550  @ 2.67GHz
stepping    : 5
cpu MHz     : 2660.076
cache size  : 8192 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 8
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 1
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc ida nonstop_tsc pni monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm
bogomips    : 5320.07
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: [8]

processor   : 10
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 26
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5550  @ 2.67GHz
stepping    : 5
cpu MHz     : 2660.076
cache size  : 8192 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 8
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 19
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc ida nonstop_tsc pni monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm
bogomips    : 5320.04
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: [8]

processor   : 11
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 26
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5550  @ 2.67GHz
stepping    : 5
cpu MHz     : 2660.076
cache size  : 8192 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 8
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 3
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc ida nonstop_tsc pni monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm
bogomips    : 5320.00
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: [8]

processor   : 12
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 26
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5550  @ 2.67GHz
stepping    : 5
cpu MHz     : 2660.076
cache size  : 8192 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 8
core id     : 2
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 21
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc ida nonstop_tsc pni monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm
bogomips    : 5320.03
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: [8]

processor   : 13
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 26
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5550  @ 2.67GHz
stepping    : 5
cpu MHz     : 2660.076
cache size  : 8192 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 8
core id     : 2
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 5
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc ida nonstop_tsc pni monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm
bogomips    : 5320.05
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: [8]

processor   : 14
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 26
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5550  @ 2.67GHz
stepping    : 5
cpu MHz     : 2660.076
cache size  : 8192 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 8
core id     : 3
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 23
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc ida nonstop_tsc pni monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm
bogomips    : 5320.02
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: [8]

processor   : 15
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 26
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5550  @ 2.67GHz
stepping    : 5
cpu MHz     : 2660.076
cache size  : 8192 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 8
core id     : 3
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 7
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc ida nonstop_tsc pni monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm
bogomips    : 5320.04
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: [8]
```

Comment: Why downvote? This mapping needed for assigning threads of big openmp program statically to cores. This was recommended by Agner Fog.

Comment: Probably because it's on the wrong site. But instead of downvoting, people should just flag it to be moved.

Comment: and what site it should be? It is about linux kernel algorithms.

Comment: try pasting the output of `cpuinfo`.. but, why does it matter which one is the psihical one ad the "virtual" one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is already solved by [Portable Hardware Locality (hwloc)](http://www.open-mpi.org/projects/hwloc/).

This utility will show how system is organized in terms of sharing physical packages, caches, physical cores. It supports HT and Linux too.

Answer (score 4):

The ones that share the same physical core should have the same core id and physical id, with different processor number. Try this:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo |egrep "processor|physical id|core id" | sed 's/^processor/\nprocessor/g'
```

Answer (score 2):

I parse /proc/cpuinfo like

`paste <(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "core id") <(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "processor") | sed 's/[[:blank:]]/ /g'`

The output on my machine looks like:

`core id  : 0 processor : 0
core id  : 1 processor : 1
core id  : 2 processor : 2
core id  : 3 processor : 3
core id  : 0 processor : 4
core id  : 1 processor : 5
core id  : 2 processor : 6
core id  : 3 processor : 7`

This shows 4 cores with two threads each.